# What are the conditions for a Bon Mot retort?

Tags: feats, skills, pathfinder-2e

The Bon Mot skill feat imposes a minute long status penalty on a foe with a successful Diplomacy check. This penalty can be ended in the following circumstance:

> The target can end the effect early with a retort to your Bon Mot. This can either be a single action that has the concentrate trait or an appropriate skill action to frame their retort. The GM determines which skill actions qualify, though they must take at least 1 action. Typically, the retort needs to use a linguistic Charisma-based skill action.

I'm left wondering what exactly are the conditions of the retort, as I don't think this text makes it clear:

- If the foe takes "a single action with the concentrate trait", do they just freely end the penalty, or do they make a skill check to do so?
- If the foe uses a skill action to retort, do they have to succeed to remove the penalty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Taking a Concentrate Action or a Skill Action

Paraphrasing the text here I'll split it into two for clarity, "The target can end the effect by making a retort to your Bon Mot as a single action that has the concentrate trait".

With no mention of any check being required, this just ends the ability at the cost of the target spending 1 action.

The other half of the text covers the skill action option, "The target can end the effect by making a retort to your Bon Mot as an appropriate skill action that takes at least 1 action. Typically this must be a Charisma-based skill action, the GM determines whether an action is appropriate".

This does mention using a skill, but still nothing about requiring a successful check. The only requirement is that again the target spends 1 action to remove the effect, with the main advantage being that the target can get rid of the effect while also achieving something else.